# What are some known ways to push data from web api to a windows form client

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble finding some documentation or services available to help push data to clients on winforms. (Maybe my search query sucks)

Ex.
I open an application on my phone which sends a request to a web api controller to run some code in a windows form app that is already running somewhere else. (for example, my PC)

I can find an abundance of information on Azure Notifications Hub and push messaging when it comes to mobile devices and windows store 8 apps but not for plain old winforms app.

I am aware I can create a que on a db and poll it with clients but want to see if there is a way to avoid polling scenarios.

**What are some known ways to push data from web api to a windows form client?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Learn About ASP.NET SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.

Here is a sample in the topic area.

[Using SignalR in WinForms and WPF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b)

[Implementing SignalR in Desktop Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications)

[ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - .NET Client (C#)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client)

> This document provides an introduction to using the Hubs API for
>   SignalR version 2 in .NET clients, such as Windows Store (WinRT), WPF,
>   Silverlight, and console applications.
>
> The SignalR Hubs API enables you to make remote procedure calls (RPCs)
>   from a server to connected clients and from clients to the server. In
>   server code, you define methods that can be called by clients, and you
>   call methods that run on the client. In client code, you define
>   methods that can be called from the server, and you call methods that
>   run on the server. SignalR takes care of all of the client-to-server
>   plumbing for you.

Comment: I was under the impression this was only for web clients as one of the main components is js. I've used this in web applications, just not winforms

Comment: [Using SignalR in WinForms and WPF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b)

Comment: @Adrian careful winform is supported by only since Win 8